# When Pushing elements into array, same elements are repeated replacing previous one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm creating an Dynamic form in angular js and when I'm adding new input fields as table row,and when pushing these objects into an array, previous element is replaced with copy of new element. Keys are same but values are different and also adding 'id' key before pushing into array.

```
JS
else if (el.type === 4) { //table   
 var x = 0;
 $scope.row = []; //to store KEY OF  table
 $scope.thead = []; //store the heading of the table | also to make row      structure
 $scope.myFm[el.value] = []; //store row of table [ INVOICE ] myFm.invoice
 $scope.colInput = {}; //values of input of each row
 $scope.colInput.id = 0;
 $scope.rowIndex = 0;
 //iterate over column_heading
 el.column_heading.forEach(function(elem) { //objects in column_heading
    $scope.row[x] = elem.val; //the object with key names of row
    $scope.thead.push(elem); //column headings
    x++;
 })
 //pusing each row to myFm[el.value] | invoice
 $scope.addNew = function(rowObj) {
    // $scope.rowIndex++;
    console.log('ROW ', rowObj);
    rowObj.id = $scope.rowIndex;
    $scope.myFm[el.value].push(rowObj);
    console.log("Invoice", $scope.myFm[el.value]);
    $scope.rowIndex++;
    console.log("ROW", rowObj);
 }

 var row = "<tr ng-repeat='r in myFm." + el.value + " track by id' ><td ng-repeat='i in row'><input ng-model='colInput[i]' class='form-control' placeholder='Enter {[{ i }]}'></td></tr>"

  item = "<label>" + el.heading + "<button ng-click='addNew(colInput)' class='m-l-lg btn font-bold'>ADD NEW</button></label>  <table class='table'><thead><th ng-repeat='th in thead'>{[{ th.name }]}</th><thead>" + "<tbody>" + row + "</tbody><table>";
}
return item
}
// adding each element from list to DOM. $compile is needed to add the     modified element to DOM
$scope.data.forEach(function(el) { //traversing over json object from the   server                 
  var item = verifyItem(el);
  var linkFn = $compile(item);
  var content = linkFn($scope); 
  element.append(content);
});
// adding the submit button to DOM
var linkFn = $compile('<button type="submit" ng-click="submitFm()"  class="m- t-lg m-b-lg btn btn-danger">Submit </button>');
var content = linkFn($scope);
element.append(content);
```

When i',m passing 'colInput' to the 'addNew' function, and adding 'id' key each time i push new object to array '$scope.myFm[el.value]', the duplicates are being created ie: the newly added is replacing the previous objects, hence i cant 'ng-repeat' it by 'track by id'.

CONSOLE

```
Invoice Array [ Object, Object, Object ]
```

these three objects have values of last pushed object.

how do i fix it.

Comment: Put your code plnkr.co, so it would help to rectify issue.

Comment: try to pass "i" as a parameter instead of colInput
" <button ng-click='addNew(i)' "

Comment: its like when new object is created, the old one is also changed. its like instances not copy.